# Rails JSON.parse "unexpected token" error

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I have a simple controller that is hit by webhooks. I need to store all data sent in a  model's `metadata` which is a `text` column for later consumption.

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    notification = Notification.new(
      metadata: params,
    )
    if notification.save
      head :ok
    end
  end
end
```

When I inspect `params.class` inside any controller action, I get an `ActionController::Parameters` object that acts like a hash.

However, when storing `params` in the `metadata` as shown above, I get a string that looks like this:

```
"{\"SmsSid\"=>\"ID\", \"SmsStatus\"=>\"STATUS\",\"controller\"=>\"notifications\", \"action\"=>\"create\"}"
```

I tried converting that string back to a hash, but doing `JSON.parse(params)` throws the following error:

```
JSON::ParserError: 783: unexpected token at "{\"SmsSid\"=>\"ID\", \"SmsStatus\"=>\"STATUS\",\"controller\"=>\"notifications\", \"action\"=>\"create\"}"
```

Is this because the column type is `text` and not `jsonb`? If so, is there any workaround that does not involve a DB migration to change the column type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I inspect params.class inside any controller action, I get an ActionController::Parameters object that acts like a hash.

Yes, this is what `params` is. It's an object, that acts like a `hash` in most respects.

> However, when storing params in the metadata as shown above, I get a string that looks like this:
>
> ```
> "{\"SmsSid\"=>\"ID\", \"SmsStatus\"=>\"STATUS\",\"controller\"=>\"notifications\", \"action\"=>\"create\"}"
> ```

Yes, because you're asking Rails to take something that is not a string, and convert it to a string so it can be stored in a `text` column. Rails does this by calling `.to_s` on the object, which returns the string representation you're seeing here.

> I tried converting that string back to a hash, but doing JSON.parse(params) throws the following error:

That string isn't JSON. If you want to serialize the `params` hash to JSON, you can use the [serialization API](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html) to define how the column should be serialized, and then save **some safe subset of params**:

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :metadata, JSON
end

...

notification = Notification.new(
  metadata: params.permit(:SmsSid, :SmsStatus),
)
```

Afterwards, you can access `notification.params` and it will be transparently deserialized for you.

Note that simply dumping the entire unsanitized `params` object into your database is a great way to allow attackers to flood your database with gigabytes of garbage text. You should never assume that `params` is safe; only work with a subset of `params` that you expect, and make sure the associated values conform to your expectations. Simply using `params.permit(...)` as I've done above is still not sufficient, as the values could be extremely long, or contain arbitrary garbage. You should use validators on your model to enforce length and format restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

I think storing the data as json string can solve the problem. like this:

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    notification = Notification.new(
      metadata: params.to_json,
    )
    if notification.save
      head :ok
    end
  end
end
```

Then:

```
JSON.parse(Notification.first.metadata)
```

or you can override the metadata getter method if don't want to write the above code everywhere

```
class Notification < ApplicationRecord

  def metadata
    JSON.parse(self[:metadata])
  end
end
```

Comment: There is no need to reinvent this wheel: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html